# get value of combobox with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have html code like this:

```
<select name="xcontract_id" onchange="jf_get_einv_disable(document.MYFORM);fenable(document.MYFORM);jf_best_contract(document.getElementById('xcust_icorcID').value,document.getElementById('xcontract_id').value);jf_check_dlstart_1_3_contr(document.getElementById('xcust_icorcID').value,document.getElementById('xcontract_id').value,document.getElementById('xsim_cnt').value);">
<option selected="">choose
<option value="14030">8N_870MHz_0106
<option value="14031">8N_870MHz_Norma_0106
<option value="48414">AX_AI_nova_akt_DZ_NTBK_24m_0103
.
.
.
</option></select>
```

and i have js functions declareted like this:

```
jf_get_einv_disable(frm){
...
//var typzmluvy=frm.xcontract_id.options[frm.xcontract_id.selectedIndex].value;
var typzmluvy=frm.xcontract_id.value;
...}
```

but when i dont change the default value of combobox (so i have still "choose") the variable is set to "choose" instead of "" or null. The first declaration is commented, because i try the second, but none of them works.
What im doing wrong? Thanks for any reply or help.
Ondro

ps:html doesnt have closing tag, because i copy it from ie developers tools.

Comment: Set an empty value to `choose` option as: `<option value="">choose</option>`

Comment: Using IE for development? Hardcore.

Comment: customer using IE, so dont have another option

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

`<option value="" selected>choose</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Use

`<option value="0" selected="selected">choose</option>`

so you can validate it.

Comment: pls have a look at this, i have copied the html code from ie developer tools (using "Copy inner html") and when i paste it into libreoffice, the value part is missing, but, as you can see, in ie developer tools, it is there. Whats is wrong?
http://s23.postimg.org/ovcy40lh5/Untitled.png

Comment: first give `id="xcontract_id"` to your combobox then use `alert(document.getElementById("xcontract_id"))` see what is return.